# Binding custom register and facebook login for SQL database

Tags: sql, facebook

I am trying to create an app with SQL database connection. Like  other apps, user should have the option of both custom register(email,password) and facebook login.

If user choose custom login thats fine, but if user choose facebook login my app would be able to retrieve email from facebook yet no password.

In most apps if you choose facebook login, after login with facebook you never deal with register and logging again (Single sign on, and access token).

But How other apps let user register without choosing a password? Do they let password field null in database (that doesnt seem feasible)?  Or do they create a random password for user and save it to users device? What if user logs out or delete their facebook account  and wants to login to my app, how would they login without password since in first place they have chosen facebook login?

I know multiple question but they are all related and I am having a difficult time understanding that simple task.

Thanks
M. Fustang

Answer (score 0):

In general if you allow people to register using Facebook, you can force them to set their username and password for this website on first time they log in. And simply store user's id from Facebook as a column in users' table together with username and password provided by user. And then allow them to login using this user/pass data for your website or using Facebook. This will allow your users to log in even after Facebook's account removal.